# Test URL to MVC Controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, routes

I have seen some very helpful posts about testing Microsoft's routing. One in particular www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/ seems to deal just with WebApi. Though similiar they are not the same. If I have an MVC application how do I see the method that will be invoked for a given URL. It seems to boils down to creating a 'Request' that can be passed to the constructor of HttpControllerContext and obtaining a reference to the 'current' config (like HttpConfiguration) in testing. Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Testing Incoming URL**

If you need to test routes, you need to mock three classes from the MVC Framework: HttpRequestBase, HttpContextBase and HttpResponseBase(only for outgoing URL´s)

```
private HttpContextBase CreateHttpContext(string targetUrl = null, string httpMethod = "GET")
    {
        // create mock request
        Mock<HttpRequestBase> mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        // url you want to test through the property 
        mockRequest.Setup(m => m.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns(targetUrl);
        mockRequest.Setup(m => m.HttpMethod).Returns(httpMethod);

        // create mock response
        Mock<HttpResponseBase> mockResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        mockResponse.Setup(m => m.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(s => s);

        // create the mock context, using the request and response
        Mock<HttpContextBase> mockContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Response).Returns(mockResponse.Object);

        // return the mock context object
        return mockContext.Object;
    }
```

then you need an additional helper method that let´s you specify the URL to test and the expected segment variables and an object for additional variables.

```
        private void TestRouteMatch(string url, string controller, string action, 
        object routeProperties = null, string httpMethod = "GET")
    {
        // arrange
        RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
        // loading the defined routes about the Route-Config
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        RouteData result = routes.GetRouteData(CreateHttpContext(url, httpMethod));

        // assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        // here you can check your properties (controller, action, routeProperties) with the result
        Assert.IsTrue(.....);
    }
```

You don´t need to define your routes in the test methodes, because they were load directly using the **RegisterRoutes** method in the **RouteConfig** class.

The mechanism by wich inbound URL matching works.

```
GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
```

[referencesource.microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Routing/RouteCollection.cs)

The framework calls this method for each route table entry, until one of thems returns a non-null value.

You have to call the helper method as example in this way

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIncomingRoutes() {
        // check for the URL that is hoped for
        TestRouteMatch("~/Home/Index", "Home", "Index");
    }
```

the method check the URL you expecting as in the example above, call the Index action in the Home controller. You must prefix the URL with tilde (~) this is they way how the ASP.NET Framework presents the URL to the routing system.

In reference to the book **Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 by Adam Freeman** i can recommand it to every ASP.NET MVC developer!

Comment: When I do this I get an InvalidOperationException on
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
with the message that "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase." Can this method be modified to take attribute routes?

Comment: @KevinBurton move MapMvcAttributeRoutes to the Global.asax.cs file -- RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();